# Refresh file using div jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, templates, refresh, smarty

I have this `.tpl` file:

```
{include file="companies-list.tpl"}
```

I want to auto refresh every 5 sec that `{include file="companies-list.tpl"}` using div jQuery. 
It is possible ?

Comment: you need to make an ajax call using jquery and set interval using timer

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
       var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
       jQuery("#divid").load(yourfilename,
        function(response, status, xhr) {           
                    if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    jQuery("#youdiv").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                          }
                });
         },5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a page that will render out just that included file.

```
setInterval( function() { $('#yourdiv').load("companies-list.php"); }, 5000 );
```

This isn't ideal (needs error checking and the ability to timeout, etc.) but it should get you on the right track.